# Visual Studio Code EIO error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VSCode and my virtual network drive.
The drive is a SFTP drive mounted with Expandrive 5.0.15.

The problem appeared when i try to open a folder with VSCode but not when i open a single file.

[image]

So I don't know what is the problem but there is an error with Node, I guest...

Does someone have an idea ?
Maybe an encoding problem ?
The SFTP server running on Ubuntu and I'm on Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it fails to read the directory at Z:\colibri. If you are able to write a small node.js script that calls fs.readdir() on that folder, we could see if this already happens with a bare node.js.

Comment: Sorry for the kinda late response ! So on a local node server I'm getting no error when i read the folder :/. The strange thing is I can create file in the folder but i don't see all the files and folders of the directory..

Comment: Can you try with io.js? VSCode ships with version 1.6.x.

Comment: I tested on my laptop with node and io and i got the same error as the web console gave me ! EIO errno-4070, but with node it work on my desktop (didn't try io on my desktop)

Comment: Ok, good to know. Does it work with the latest io.js version?

Comment: Tested with 1.6.4 and 3.3 and nop :/ .. Just to be clear, VS Code doesn't work on both, my desktop and laptop. But the readdir work on my desktop but not my laptop. Should i try io 1.6 on my desktop ?

Comment: If you have a valid bug against latest io.js, you should report it at their repository https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2689#issuecomment-137692085